# How to center an image over another image in CSS

Tags: css, html, image

I want to put book image thumbnails and their titles/author over another image. It took some time to get the bottom image to show under the paragraph text instead of breaking up. Now that I've fixed that, I can't figure out how to get the book images back in the top center of the image behind it. So, I'm just looking to get those thumbnail images centered on top of the white image behind them. Here's the page:   mcs.athens.edu/~lgeorge1/books.html

EDIT: Now I would like to know how to make the text (authors/title) centered under the book image. I would have thought text-align: center; would have done it but no. It's driving my OCD crazy, haha.

And my code:

```
div.thumbnail
{width: 250px;
text-align: center;
float: left;
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
background: url(images/white2.jpg) no-repeat;
}
.thumbnail img
{margin: 30px 0 0 40px;
width: 150px;
border: 1px solid #777;
}
.thumbnail p
{margin: 0;
padding: 10px 30px 40px 10px;
background: url(images/white2.jpg) no-repeat 0 100%;
}
.clear{clear: left;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember when you wanna center a nontext block, use `margin:0 auto;` which is intended for that. Also if you make image `display:inline-block` I think you could use `text-align:center`
Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, text-align didn't work when I added display:inline-block to the img. But I'll try to remember the margin: 0 auto; 'cause that centered the image. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

what you need to change is the margin style of your thumbnail img, ie:

```
.thumbnail img {
   margin: 0 auto; /* this will center the image */
}
```

Then just put the margin-top on the parent a element, ie:

```
.thumbnail a {
   display: block; /* need this to wrap it around child image */
   margin-top: 30px; /* add your margin top here */
}
```

I could suggest some cleaner markup and styles to achieve the same results, but the suggested changes above should work for your markup.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. It actually pushed the book images (top images) up further so the top sticks out and isn't on the image behind it. I actually got it centered by changing my margins around in .thumbnail img

Comment: well as explained you needed to apply display: block to your parent a element and set the margin-top there to fix the top sticking out. Worked fine when I tested it.

Answer (score 0):

for images:

```
    div.thumbnail {
    width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
    background: url('images/white2.gif') no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    height: 350px;
}
```

and for paragraphs:

```
.thumbnail p {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 152px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You shouldn't use the `background` or `padding` for paragraph, instead you should specify a height to the thumbnail.

Comment: Do you know how to make the text under the book image centered with that image? At least centered within the image behind it? I thought text-align: center; would do it but it didn't.